# не понятен суффикc 15000128L в python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

getsizeof() в питоне выдает нам размер в байтах, но применяя в одному объекту, я получил следующий результат: `15000128L`, то есть мне не понятен суффикc, применяя к обычным переменным, я получаю только цифру. Где можно почитать про эти спецификации? или же что это значит?

Comment: Если целое число заканчивается знаком l или L, оно рассматривается как целое неограниченного размера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суффикс `L` – это `long`.

Объект у которого вы запрашиваете размер, наверное, какой-нибудь большой контейнер, раз он 14.3 МБ занимает.

Comment: `15000128L` само по себе слишком маленькое число скорее всего (меньше `sys.maxsize`) поэтому обычно суффикс `L` не должен появляться. Промежуточные вычисления такие как `sys.maxsize + 1 - sys.maxsize` могут создать "длинное" маленькое число, хотя не очевидно откуда в `sys.getsizeof()` большие числа берутся если результат маленький.